# What's the nature of Cassandra "write timeout"?

Tags: cassandra, timeout

I am running a write-heavy program (10 threads peaks at 25K/sec writes) on a 24 node Cassandra 3.5 cluster on AWS EC2 (each host is of c4.2xlarge type: 8 vcore and 15G ram)

Every once in a while my Java client, using DataStax driver 3.0.2, would get write timeout issue:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency TWO (2 replica were required but only 1 acknowledged the write)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException.copy(WriteTimeoutException.java:73)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException.copy(WriteTimeoutException.java:26)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:64)
```

The error happens infrequently and in a very unpredictable way. So far, I am not able to link the failures to anything specific (e.g. program running time, data size on disk, time of the day, indicators of system load such as CPU, memory, network metrics) Nonetheless, it is really disrupting our operations.

I am trying to find the root cause of the issue. Looking online for options, I am a bit overwhelmed by all the leads out there, such as

- Changing "write_request_timeout_in_ms" in "cassandra.yaml" (already changed to 5 seconds)
- Using proper "RetryPolicy" to keep the session going (already using DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy on a ONE session level consistency level)
- Changing cache size, heap size, etc. - never tried those b/c there are good reasons to discount them as the root cause.

One thing is really confusing during my research is that I am getting this error from a fully replicated cluster with very few ClientRequest.timeout.write events:

- I have a fully-replicated 24 node cluster spans 5 aws regions. Each region has at least 2 copies of the data
- My program runs consistency level ONE at Session level (Cluster builder with QueryOption)
- When the error happened, our Graphite chart registered no more than three (3) host hiccups, i.e. having the Cassandra.ClientRequest.Write.Timeouts.Count values
- I already set write_timeout to 5 seconds. The network is pretty fast (using iperf3 to verify) and stable

On paper, the situation should be well within Cassandra's failsafe range. But why my program still failed? Are the numbers not what they appear to be?

Comment: We have the same issue, sometimes write timeouts happens, especially often when we lose connection between cassandra data centers (we have bad bandwith between datacanters) and even requests within local datacenter fail with timeouts. But according to the cassandra write path write timeouts are not a failures, so we implemented custom retry policy for cassandra driver to ignore write timeouts and it works fine in eventually consistency requirements

Comment: +1 Thanks Mikhail. In my case, I forgot to mention that my program uses BatchStatement. I just came across this post http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-error-handling-done-right which suggested further detecting the failed write type: whether it is BATCH or BATCH_LOG. In my case, I got both. I can understand the driver failing at BATCH_LOG but don't get it why I am still getting BATCH failures. In addition to my original question (that I should have plenty of nodes to send replica to), I am also applying DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy, which should have ignored that error already.

Comment: Bing, How many operations are in your batch? Maybe it is too big and can not be processed within timeout

Comment: Mikhail - I capped the batch size to 50. The average data size has been between 5-10K (since the warning threshold was set to 5K so I got to see the actuals from the logs). I have since discovered the majority of the timeouts are of BATCH_LOG WriteType. So you are probably right - maybe the batch size is the issue. I am hesitant to change b/c timeout happens infrequently yet the perf gain using batch is significant. I did try async write but ran into driver OOM issue similar to CASSANDRA-10689. So I opted adding a recovery mechanism to my code instead.

Comment: I have same problem, and my measurement show me, that this exception appeared much early then 2 seconds(default timeout) exceed.

Comment: @BingWu I'm a bit late to this one, but I've seen this with GC issues whereby GC pauses C* on enough nodes to trigger availability issues leading to timeouts. Review your gc logs to see if you're finding extended GCs. 15G is a significantly sized heap to start having issues if it's not running under a well tuned jvm.

Answer (score 4):

Its not always necessarily a bad thing to see timeouts or errors especially if you're writing at a higher consistency level, the writes may still get through.

I see you mention `CL=ONE` you could still get timeouts here but the write (mutation) still have got through. I found this blog really useful: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-error-handling-done-right. Check your server side (node) logs at the time of the error to see if you have things like ERROR / WARN / GC pauses (like one of the comments mentions above) these kind of events can cause the node to be unresponsive and therefor a timeout or other type of error.

If your updates are idempotent (ideally) then you can build in some retry mechanism.