# Write C* timeout appeared in unpredictable way

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

We have same [situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39304074/whats-the-nature-of-cassandra-write-timeout) with lightweight-transaction, but i can't use retry because of bug in java driver Issue. https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1088

What i absolutely sure.

My C* write timeout is 2 seconds(default)
My cassandra is 9 node /16gb with EBS(GP2): and it does not overload. 1-3 %cpu...
My load is 600 call insert/update per sec.
And i know this exception

`com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency LOCAL_SERIAL (2 replica were required but only 1 acknowledged the write)`

This timeout Appeared much early (500-900ms) then configured timeout exceed.

Does some one get any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

**Caution with Lightweight Transactions (LWT)**

Lightweight Transactions are currently considered a Cassandra anti-pattern because of the performance issues you are suffering.

LTW comes with big performance penalties if used frequently, and we see some clients with big timeout issues due to using LWTs.

Lightweight transactions are generally a bad idea and should be used infrequently.

If you want to check more about this topic please check this answer in Stackoverflow: [How to executing batch statement and LWT as a transaction in Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50420368/5102653)

Comment: I don't have problem with LWT, i know why they so slow and all their restrictions. I need them, because of my logic. And I'am ok to suffer with performance. BUT I DON'T UNDERSTAND WHY I HAVE TIMEOUT EXCEPTION, BEFORE 2s(DEFAULT TIMEOUT CONF) EXPIRED.